# Using design documents in pouchDB with crypto-pouch

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb, documents

After testing pouchDB for my Ionic project, I tried to encrypt my data with crypto-pouch. But I have a problem with using design documents. I used the following code:

1. One of my design documents:

   ```
   var allTypeOne = {
     _id: '_design/all_TypeOne',
       views: {
           'alle_TypeOne': {
           map: function (doc) {
               if (doc.type === 'type_one') {
                   emit(doc._id);
               }
           }.toString()
         }
       }
   };
   ```
2. For init my database:

   ```
   function initDB() {
     _db = new PouchDB('myDatabase', {adapter: 'websql'});
     if (!_db.adapter) {
       _db = new PouchDB('myDatabase');
     }
     return _db.crypto(password)
       .then(function(){
         return _db;
       });

     // add a design document
     _db.put(allTypeOne).then(function (info) {

     }).catch(function (err) {

     }
   }
   ```
3. To get all documents of type_one:

   ```
   function getAllData {
     if (!_data) {
       return $q.when(_db.query('all_TypeOne', { include_docs: true}))
         .then(function(docs) {
           _data = docs.rows.map(function(row) {
             return row.doc;
           });
           _db.changes({ live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true})
             .on('change', onDatabaseChange);
           return _data;
         });
     } else {
       return $q.when(_data);
     }
   }
   ```

This code works without using crypto-pouch well, but if I insert the _db.crypto(...) no data is shown in my list. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your put is happening before the call to crypto has finished. Remember, javascript is asynchronous. So wait for the crypto call to finish before putting your design doc. And then use a callback to access your database after it's all finished. Something like the following:

```
function initDB(options) {
  _db = new PouchDB('myDatabase', {adapter: 'websql'});
  if (!_db.adapter) {
    _db = new PouchDB('myDatabase');
  }

  _db.crypto(password)
    .then(function(){
       // add a design document
       _db.put(allTypeOne).then(function (info) {
         options.success(_db);
       })
      .catch(function (err) { console.error(err); options.error(err)})
    .catch(function (err) { console.error(err); options.error(err);})
  }
}

initDB({
  success:function(db){
    db.query....
  }
)
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it didn't help. Meanwhile I found out, that the problem was the listener for changes. When I removed it, the encryption and even design documents worked without any problem.